# How to import C++ dll from c# using PInvoke?

Tags: c#, c++, interop

The definition of the exported function in c++ DLL is

```
int func1(const char* input,char** output)
{
 int returnCode = 0;

 std::stringstream xmlInputStream;
 xmlInputStream<< std::string(input);
 std::stringstream xmlOutputStream;
 returnCode = doRequest(xmlInputStream,xmlOutputStream);
 std::string xmlOutputString =xmlOutputStream.str();
 *output=const_cast<char *> (xmlOutputString.c_str());

cout<<xmlOutputString;

 return returnCode ;
}
```

I tried to import the function from c# like this...

```
==================================================================

[DllImport("sample.dll")]
    public static extern int func1(String str1,out String str2);


string str1="hello";
string str2=String.Empty;

MyClass.func1(str1,out str2);
Console.writeln(str2);

====================================================================
```

Output is garbage value...

Why is it so and how to import this function from c#?

Comment: What are you doing in func1 w.r.t str2?

Comment: Actually in func1 iam creating another char* and assigning it to str2. and this need to be read from a c# program...and iam not much familiar with c#.

Comment: @user186246: You finally getting an address to look into for c_str(), so you can freely use my method, create ByteArray structure and declare 2 paramenter as out ByteArray* char, then you can get a apointer to that data as an ByteArray.ptr memory pointer, and extract that data from memory

Comment: @Artur - my concern with your answer is that it uses unsafe code, which IMO should be avoided whenever possible. If indeed MarshalAs (in my answer) is not sufficient, so be it, but unsafe code and dealing with pointers in managed code should be, by far, a last resort.

Comment: @Austin Lamb: Yes, indeed. sometimes using a memory pointers technique to reverse an algorithms is a really last resort/i have to study something completely special, like "compilation theory", to understand how to deal with nothing but in-memory pointters to data structures

Comment: @user186246: You are welcome to check my final code, I hope it will answer all the questions you have at the moment

Comment: @Artur: OK. Without making any change in my previous code of C# it worked with the changes done in the C++ function.Now Iam using:     [DllImport("sample.dll")]                                     public static extern int func1(String str1,out String str2);         please correct me if iam wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats simple, try to use custom marshaling (especially if you want to use char** pointers).

I found that you are no getting "Memory ass dumb" string, because of some improper realization of doRequest(char*,char**), as well as assigning to the result is not properly handled;

Firstly, if you are allocating memory in unmanaged process and passes it to managed process, you will need declare some mechanism to free unmanaged memory. Managed GC does not know anything about this memory, which will be lost overwize.

Secondy, you need to allocate memory for the results, and pass them to the unmanaged process, because the original memory locations can be rewritten in any time.

Lastly, you are getting only the first characted of the input just because you are not allocated memory for the results, effectively passing only a memory pointer to the memory location of the first output character, say &array[0]

Here is the compete code (MS VC++/MS C#), which fixes all the issues:

lib.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "lib.h"
using namespace std;

int func1(char* input, char** output)
{
    stringstream xmlInputStream, xmlOutputStream;

    xmlInputStream << string(input);    
    int returnCode = doRequest(&xmlInputStream, &xmlOutputStream);
    string xmlOutputString = xmlOutputStream.str();

    //*output=const_cast<char *> (xmlOutputString.c_str());
    long length = sizeof(char) * xmlOutputString.length();
    char* src = const_cast<char *>(xmlOutputString.c_str());
    char* dst = (char*)malloc(length+1);
    memcpy_s(dst, length, src, length);
    dst[length]=0; // 0 byte always ends up given ANSI string
    *output = dst;

    //cout << xmlOutputString;
    return returnCode;
}

int func1_cleanup(char* memptr)
{
    free(memptr);
    return 0;
}


int doRequest(stringstream* xmlInputStream, stringstream* xmlOutputStream)
{
    *xmlOutputStream << "Memory ass dumb";
    return 0;
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("lib.dll", EntryPoint = "func1", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern unsafe int func1(char* input, char** data);

        [DllImport("lib.dll", EntryPoint = "func1_cleanup", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern unsafe int func1_cleanup(char* data);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "Hello, World!";
            string output;
            int result = func1(input, out output);
        }

        private const int S_OK = 0;

        public static int func1(string input, out string output)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                output = null;
                int result = -1;
                fixed (char* parray1 = &input.ToCharArray()[0])
                {
                    //
                    // if you allocating memory in a managed process, you can use this
                    //
                    //char[] array = new char[0xffffff];
                    //fixed(char* parray = &array[0])
                    {
                        //
                        // if you allocating memory in unmanaged process do not forget to cleanup the prevously allocated resources
                        //
                        char* array = (char*)0; 
                        char** parray2 = &array;
                        result = func1(parray1, parray2);
                        if (result == S_OK)
                        {
                            //
                            // if your C++ code returns the ANSI string, you can skip this extraction code block (it can be useful in Unicode, UTF-8, UTF-7, UTF-32, all C# supported encodings)
                            //
                            //byte* self = (byte*)*((int*)parray2);
                            //byte* ptr = self;
                            //List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
                            //do
                            //{
                            //    bytes.Add(*ptr++);
                            //}
                            //while (*ptr != (byte)0);
                            //output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
                            output = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new IntPtr(*parray2));
                        }
                        func1_cleanup(array);
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unnecessary; StringBulder works and is designed for the OP's issue.

Comment: Cant we use string instead of IntPtr?

Comment: @Ed Swangren: Where is your answer? I did not head, where you can use StringBuilder to work as char*, char** marshaller. Give me a sample, please

Comment: @user186246: No, since you have an char**

Comment: @Artur: ptr_str2 isn't defined in func1

Comment: Hi Artur I have tried your approach but Iam getting a single character when Iam displaying the second parameter in the above function

Comment: @user186246: i'm already work with your question, I've been created a C++ class at work, can you pleas show me a doProcessing() function? In my working sample (pot published yet) all is working OK. I'm still thinking that something goes wrong in C++ not in C#. I will try to reproduce your full story and fix it completely

Comment: @Zach Saw: Code has chaned. Your issue had been fixed

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work

```
[DllImport("sample.dll")]
public static extern int func1(
    [MarhsalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String str1,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] out String str2);
```

The MarshalAs attribute is awesomely powerful for controlling interop.

**EDIT** (based on updated post with C++ code):

Maybe something more like this should work (I don't have VC++ on this computer to build a fake C++ DLL to check)

```
[DllImport("sample.dll")]
public static extern int func1(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String str1,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst=1), Out] out String[] str2);
```

Note I added [Out] to the str2, I'm not sure this is good or necessary, so try with and without that (again, sorry, I can't try here).  Also, you may need to use SizeParamIndex instead of SizeConst, I can't remember - if it needs to be SizeParamIndex, you'd need to change the C++ code to pass back 1 as the number of array elements.

This passes back str2 as a String[], but you can then just use the first element of that array to get the string.

There may be cleaner ways of doing this, too - a __deref_out parameter in C++ doesn't translate really well to C# that I remember, but I may be forgetting some of the arcana here.

Comment: @Austin Lamb: +1, That will work, if a data structures passed to char** is an ordinal ones, not a sparse arrays, for example, if ever you will get something unusual, you will fall into my solution immediately ;)

Comment: Saying "it didn't work" doesn't help very much - can you elaborate?  What happened when you tried it?  Does the native side get str1 correctly?  Can you show the code for func1 in C++ so we can understand how str2 gets set?  What does come back in str2 on the managed side?

Comment: @user186246: result is an array of array of char, so probably it can be translated to ( out String[] str2).. I will work on that guess...

Comment: The output for Console.writeln(str2) is giving a garbage value in c# program.....and str1 worked correctly C++ from native code.

Comment: Again, we need to know what the C++ code is doing - do you have the source for this c++ function? As Artur points out, char** could mean an array of char*, it could simply be doing an assignment of one char* to * str2 (deref of str2), it could be binary data (char* is used many times for binary data since it's 1-byte), or lots of other things could be going on in that native function.

Comment: It is still giving a garbage value with your approach

Comment: @user186246: Yes, indeed. I managed how to work with .c_ptr(), I will check and test the results, at work in at the launch ;)

Comment: thank u so much for giving lot of information here.......actually there was problem in the c++ code itself , how i resolved is by allocating memory in the heap, copy the string to this memory and then return ...The function c_str() is returning a c pointer of string but i think it is allocating in local memory..so it gave garbage when read from C#.